# How to delete the selected text in a textbox when a div in clicked with Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm bulding a keyboard with jquery and html for a touch devise and I'm trying to figure out how to delete a specific text inside a textbox when my div.delete button is clicked. Right now I'm doing this:

My html:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>

<div class="delete key-btn">&larr; DELETE</div>
```

My jquery:

```
$( ".delete" ).click(function() {
    $('#name').val(
        function(index, value){
            return value.substr(0, value.length - 1);
    })
});
```

The problem is that I can only get to delete text starting at the last character. If the user needs to remove another character like, for example: The "a" of "Pablo" he can't.

I'm loosing the input focus() when the div is clicked. Can someone please tell me how can I achieve this with jquery or javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your event handler for a `mousedown` event. With that the `return false` statement helps you doesn't lost the input focus.

```
$(".delete").on("mousedown",function(evt) {
        var nameInput = document.querySelector("#name")
        var cursorPosition = nameInput.selectionStart;

    $("#name").val(
        function(index, value){
            return value.substr(0,cursorPosition - 1) + value.substr(cursorPosition);
    });

    nameInput.selectionStart = cursorPosition - 1;
    nameInput.selectionEnd = cursorPosition - 1;

    return false;
});
```

Comment: No. It's still deleting the last character :(

Comment: Nice solution! I like it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've added a snippet with some comments, basically you need to read the current cursor position and cut the character at a given position. If you don't want to lose focus on the input element, you just need to call `focus()` on the input again after changing its value:

```js
const deleteBtn = document.querySelector("#delete");

deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // here we're preventing the original event side-effects
  const input = document.querySelector("input[name=name]");
  const originalSelectionEnd = input.selectionEnd; // this will store current cursor position in the input field
  if (originalSelectionEnd > 0) { // as if we're at the beginning of the input there is nothing to delete
    input.value = input.value.slice(0, input.selectionEnd - 1) + input.value.slice(input.selectionEnd); // we're setting new value to the original value without a character before the cursor position
    input.selectionEnd = originalSelectionEnd - 1; // setting new cursor position
  }
  input.focus(); // and finally focus input element
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" />

<a id="delete">&larr; DELETE</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
  var $name = $('#name')[0];
  var val = $('#name').val();
  $('#name').val(val.substring(0, $name.selectionStart) + val.substring($name.selectionEnd));
});
```